# PHP Month year day selection drop down list to generate date format in middleware laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I have 3 fields in birth date, day, month and year, as 3 dropdown list. I want to store them in a single `Date_of_birth` column in the database.

How can I solve that in middleware?

#### Attempt

```
public function dob($request, Closure $next) {
    $dobrequest -> all();
    if (isset($dobrequest['day'] && $dobrequest['month'] &&                $dobrequest['year'])) {
        $dobrequest['dob'] = $dobrequest['day']."/".$dobrequest['month']."/". $dobrequest['year'];            
    }
    $request ->replace($dobrequest);
    return $next($request);
}
```

register.blade.php

```
<div class="col-md-6 pull-left" style="padding-left:0px;">
   <font size="3">  <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label><br class="clearfix" />
      <div class="form-group clearfix">
          <label for="dob_month" class="sr-only">Month</label>
                  <select name = "dob" id="m" class="form-control">
                     <option>Month</option>
                      @for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++)                  <option value = "{{ $month }}">{{ $month }}</option>                   @endfor
                    </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dob_day" id="d" class="sr-only">Day</label>
                  <select name = "dob" class="form-control">
                      <option>Day</option>
                        @for ($day = 1; $day <= 31; $day++)                    <option value = "{{ $day }}">{{ $day }}</option>                    @endfor
                  </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dob_year" id="y" class="sr-only">Year</label>
                  <select name = "dob" class="form-control">
                       <option>year</option>
                      @for ($year = 1950; $year <= 2052 ; $year++)                  <option value = "{{ $year }}">{{ $year }}</option>                  @endfor
                  </select>
      </div>

    </font>
  </div>
```

## registercontroller.php

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {

       dd($data);

        return User::create([
            'fname' => $data['fname'],
            'lname' => $data['lname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'zipcode' => $data['zipcode'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'gender' => $data['gender'],
            'dob' => $data['day'],$data['month'],$data['year'],
            'health' => $data['health'],
        ]); 

    }
```

## model-> user.php

```
protected $fillable = [
        'fname','lname', 'email','zipcode', 'password','gender','dob','health',
    ];

#migration

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('fname');
            $table->string('lname');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('zipcode');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->DATE('dob');
            $table->string('health');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }



    ];
```

Comment: Which datatype you've used into database table column?

Comment: dob DATE.  i used

Comment: Then you should store date like "Y-m-d" format. `$date = $dobrequest['year']."-".$dobrequest['month']."-". $dobrequest['day']; `

Comment: Date and Month should be in two digit like 01-05. Please change your dropdown.

Comment: not working. please check again my quetion i edited

Comment: I have checked that's why I commented. Please check your dropdown value, It should show like month and day in two digit. Print it then show me.

Comment: i changed value

Comment: <select name = "dob" id="m" class="form-control">
                      <option>Month</option>      
    <option>01</option>      
    <option>02</option>      
    <option>03</option>      
    <option>04</option>      
    <option>05</option>      
    <option>06</option>      
    <option>07</option>      
    <option>08</option>      
    <option>09</option>      
    <option>10</option>      
    <option>11</option> 
     <option>12</option>      
                    </select>

Comment: sir please help me. how to store in database this 3 field to the dob column

Comment: YOu have taken same name in select box. Please change each to day, month and year.  `<select name = "day" id="day" class="form-control">` `<select name = "month" id="month" class="form-control">` and `<select name = "year" id="month" class="form-control">`

Comment: ty sir. it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can create helper class for format date, day and year string to date format
and define function like:

```
public function formatDate($year, $month, $day) {
   return strftime("%F", strtotime($year."-".$month."-".$day));
}
```

Comment: Add this function in your `registercontroller.php` and the call this function as below:
`$formatted_date = $this->formatDate($data['year'], $data['month'], $data['day']);`
and replace 
`'dob' => $data['day'],$data['month'],$data['year'],`
with 
`'dob' =>$formatted_date,`

Comment: @VickyNehare Kindly approve the answer. TIA :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create wrap function with params day and year string and define function like:

```
function wrapDate($day, $month, $year) {
    return sprintf("%d/%d/%d", $day, $month, $year);
}
```